# RxSwift - how to chain observables sequentially

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, observable, rx-swift

Assume I have array of Ints:

```
var items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

and a function that takes Int argument and basing on it sends network request:

```
 func sendRequest(argument: Int) -> Observable<Void> {
    // sends network request
    ...
 }
```

I want to send network requests for each element of items array, but I want to do it sequentially, send next request only once previous one is finished.

My first attempt was something like this:

```
let observables = items.map{ [weak self] argument in (self?.sendRequest(argument: argument) ?? Observable.empty()) }

let result = Observable.concat(observables)
```

This approach however sends request simultaneously and only combine the results sequentially.

My second approach:

```
let items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

var result = Observable.just(Void())

for item in items {
    result = result.flatMap{ [weak self] in  
        self?.sendRequest(argument: item) ?? Observable.empty() 
    }
}
```

It seems to work, but obviously result emits next element only once all network requests finish.

What I would need is sending requests sequentially with result observable that emits next event once each single request is finished.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operator `.concatMap()` guarantees that order remains intact, as opposed to `.flatMap()`

i.e.

```swift
Observable.from([1,2,3,4,5]).concatMap( /* your request code */ )
```

**UPDATE**

```swift
let source = Observable.from([1,2,3,4,5])
let trigger = BehaviorSubject<Int>(value: 0)
let feed = Observable.zip(source, trigger) { return $0.0 }

feed.concatMap {
    /* your request code */
    trigger.onNext(0) // possibly in .onComplete of the service call
}
```

Comment: The problem is that still all requests are sent at once and my goal was to send them one by one

Comment: @MaximVolgin in your first example ` Observable.from([1,2,3,4,5]).concatMap{ return $0}.subscribe(onNext:{` I'm getting this error `Instance method 'concatMap' requires that 'Int' conform to 'ObservableConvertibleType'` any ideas?

Comment: concatMap only guarantees the order of the results. But that doesn't mean sendRequest for the second item is only called after sendRequest of the first item completes