# How to combine multi Observable in RxSwift

Tags: swift, rx-swift, reactive

Let's say I create an Observable for each image download

```
for _ in 0...N {
    let s : Single<UIImage?> = fetchImage(from url)
}
```

How can I:

- create a new Observable to emit an event when a download is completed
- create a new Observable to emit only completed event when all download is completed

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> create a new Observable to emit an event when a download is completed

Look at the method `imageObservable` for a possible implementation.

> create a new Observable to emit only completed event when all download
> is completed

The `zip` ([documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html)) operator might be what you are looking for.

```
import RxSwift
import UIKit

enum CustomError: Error {
    case someError
}

class Executer {

    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    func execute() {
        let imageURLs = [
            URL(string: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150")!, 
            URL(string: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150")!
        ]
        let imageObservables = imageURLs.map { self.imageObservable(url: $0) }
        Observable
            .zip(imageObservables) // wait for all image requests to finish
            .subscribe(onNext: { images in
                // here you have every single image in the 'images' array
                images.forEach { print($0) }
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
     }

     // wrap 'URLSession' datatask into an observable
     func imageObservable(url: URL) -> Observable<UIImage> {
        return Observable.create { observer in
            URLSession
                .shared
                .dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                    if let error = error {
                        observer.onError(error)
                        return
                    }
                    guard let data = data, let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
                        observer.onError(CustomError.someError)
                        return
                    }
                    observer.onNext(image)
                    observer.onCompleted()
                })
                .resume()
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
}
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47906030/rxswift-how-to-chain-observables-sequentially) might also be relevant for you.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Or use combineLatest http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html

Comment: Combine  Latest is great when all your observables have the Same type of element. Things get complicated if you need to perform things in sequence.